Как через браузер посмотреть на файлы, созданные через google-cloud-bigquery?
Подключился, создал файл, открыл доступ к файлу и могу по ссылке открыть этот файл. Но хотелось бы увидеть, где он физически лежит.
В каком разделе Google Cloud's можно найти созданные файлы и посмотреть на них?
А то через API:
from google.oauth2 import service_account

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pprint

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'myservice-b77593d01a7.json'
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
results = service.files().list(pageSize=10,
                               fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)").execute()

print('results:', results)

не очень удобно смотреть, да и узнать бы хотелось, сколько там места для хранения доступно.
Зашёл в CloudStorage созданного сервиса — там пусто.
Может не там смотрю?


Тут по-моему используется Google Drive (это консьюмерский продукт, https://drive.google.com/), а не Cloud Storage.
